# PHP ~ Check if a date occurs during the next (proper) week

Tags: php, date, time, compare

I've searched for this one, and I have a solution that gets dates for Monday and Friday (only looking for working week) of next week, and then checks if my date falls within that range. It works.

```
<?php
$check_count = 0 ;
$check_date = 20181127 ;

if ( $check_date >= date ( 'Ymd' , strtotime ( 'monday next week' ) ) && 
    $check_date <= date ( 'Ymd' , strtotime ( 'friday next week' ) ) ) {

    // DATE IS NEXT WEEK
    echo 'Next week!' ;
    $check_count++ ;

}
?>
```

But I would like to know if there is a one-liner of sorts, which can take a date ( 'Ymd' ) and see if it occurs "next week."

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks,
furi0usBee

Comment: Please add your current code.

Comment: Please use the `edit` function, https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53460560/edit.

Comment: Isn't that already a one liner? Do you mean a single function?

Comment: I'm actually looking to check a date that falls within Monday - Friday of the next week, not through Sunday, per the code. Sorry about that. Rough start to my account here LOL.

Comment: Rather than having to get a start/finish date for next week, I though maybe there was just a single check, such as date_interval ( "+1 weeks") or something to that effect.

Comment: `friday next week` should be friday, not saturday. Maybe your timezone is not set correctly? No way I know of for a "next week" check. You'd need start and end range.